# TinyMCE get selected text and underlying HTML

Tags: shortcode, tinymce

I already have a custom TinyMCE button that returns the selected text using

```
var selected = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
```

However, when a user creates a WordPress "link" like this...

[image: link]

...and the user selects the "Link" text, my `selected` variable will only contain the word "Link". What I need it to contain is the entire `<a>`, with the src and target and everything, so that I can parse it and inject a shortcode instead.

I have already tried `.getContent({format: 'raw'});` and the result is the same.

**How can I get TinyMCE to give me the selected underlying markup as well?**

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do what I wanted to do by using `.getNode()` instead.